# Tag "selenium-webdriver" not available at "sqa.stackexchange.com"

Tags: support, tags

I have just noticed that tag called **"selenium-webdriver"** is not available at **"sqa.stackexchange.com"**.

I have edited many question in **sqa.stackexchange.com** and not getting above tag. Same tag is available at **"https://stackoverflow.com/"**

So can someone tell me  how can I add tag to **sqa.stackexchange.com** as it is necessary for selenium web driver related questions and will help a lot.

Comment: Does the [tag:webdriver] tag not do it for you?

Comment: There is diff. between selenium-webdriver and webdriver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see where it would be useful to have a separate tags for selenium, selenium2, webdriver, and selenium-webdriver.  For the most part, Selenium2 should cover it, however, I've created the new tag.

Comment: Thanks a lot for understanding and new tag addition.